# How to do: non const member function used on objects left side and const member function used on objects right side of assignment

Tags: c++, constants, rvalue, lvalue

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
class CBuffer
{
private:
    char Array_L[10];
    char Array_R[10];
public:
    const char& AccessByte(int index) const { return Array_R[index]; }
    char& AccessByte(int index) { return Array_L[index]; }
}

int main()
{
    CBuffer myBufferL;
    CBuffer myBufferR;

    myBufferL.AccessByte(0) = myBufferR.AccessByte(0);
}
```

I assumed (and intended) `Array_R` will be accessed, because `myBufferR.GetAccess()` is right side of assignment, and `Array_L` being used on `myBufferL.GetAccess()`.

But in both cases the non const version is used. Why, and what can I do.

I know, I could change the names of `GetAccess`, to e.g `GetAccessL` and `GetAccessR`, but just imaging, using `operator[](int index)`.

Comment: Make it easy for everyone. Rename those two functions: `AccessByteL` and `AccessByteR`

Comment: Declare `myBufferR` as a `const`. Or create a separate method `void assign(CBuffer& to, const CBuffer& from);` That should work too.

Comment: Something you could do is return an wrapper object from the function with a custom implementation of the assignment operator. You shouldn't be doing this though. The code becomes very hard to maintain, if the meaning of the function seemingly could change depending on how the return value is used later. Usually you'd expect the assignment here to have the same effect as doing `char& l = myBufferL.AccessByte(0); char& r = myBufferR.AccessByte(0); l = r;` but there's absolutely no way of the references behaving the way you'd expect them to...

Answer (score 3):

> Why

This happens because both `const` and non-`const` overloads are viable in this scenario, and non-`const` is a better candidate thanks to [[over.ics.rank](3.2.6)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.6):

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if ....
>
> .... `S1` and `S2` include reference bindings ([[dcl.init.ref]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref)), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2` refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by `S1` refers.

---

> what can I do

You've already come up with a working solution - just use different names for your functions. Alternatively you can enforce `const` overload by adding `const` modifier to your right-side variable:

```cpp
int main(){
    CBuffer myBufferL;
    const CBuffer myBufferR;

    myBufferL.AccessByte(0) = myBufferR.AccessByte(0);
}
```

Comment: Everything above is clear and known. The given code is a simplification of my problem. If CBuffer for example is a ring buffer, you may want to use different Index members to store were read and write happens. Then const operator[] shall use read index, because it is read from (right side of =) and non const operator[] is used to write to and so will increment the write index.

Comment: @Chris That's simply not how C++ works.  Each operand of an assignment operator is evaluated independently.  There's no way to have the call resolve differently if it's on the left side than it does on the right side.

Comment: I heard about && in C++17 (I guess). Could this help somehow? l-value and r-value.... ?

Comment: @Chris rvalue reference overload just introduces another kind of conversion problem to you. You will have to ensure that the right side of the assignment expression is always an rvalue, similar to how currently you have to ensure cv qualifier of it

Comment: @Chris Instead of trying to make overload resolution do what you want - which doesn't work - why not simply use two differently named member functions: read and write.

Answer (score 0):

`myBufferR` is not declared `const`, so a conversion is required to call the `const` overload of `AccessByte`.  The non-const version is therefore a better match, so that's what gets called.

Solution (as already mentioned in the comments) is to declare `myBufferR` `const`.  I also agree with the comments above in general.

Incidentally, taking your example of `operator[]` (say), it would be most unusual (and ill-advised) if the `const` and non-`const` versions did fundamentally different things.  The whole point of having a `const` overload is so that you can call it on a `const` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,
I understood now, that the constantnes of an object is relevant, not the side of operand left or right of "=". I thought there is a way C++ can deduct the intention of change (left) and not change (right) and will use this to make the right operand atutomatically const, if an overloaded const method exists, because it will match better.
I was wrong.
I now implemented my problem using dedicated push (left) and pop (right) functions.

If there is still a way to deduct the "side" of "=", let me know. I always want to learn.
Chris