# Overload resolution with const-qualification

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading

Lets consider simple reduced example

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
struct Baz : Foo {};

struct X {
  operator Bar() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; return {}; }
  operator Baz() const { std::cout << "Baz\n"; return {}; }
};

void foo(const Foo &f) {}

int main() {
  foo(X{});
}
```

Here both GCC and clang are printing "Bar", see [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/cYhxW4j4G)

I am struggling to understand why.

There is no problem to call const-annotated method in rvalue object, see [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/3fjEvz66j)

So lets build ICS:

```
X{} -> user conversion -> Bar -> const Foo&
X{} -> user conversion -> Buz -> const Foo&
```

Both ICS have 1 user conversion and equivalent standard conversion tail. This shall be ambiguity by [over.ics.rank] C++20.

Can someone help to motivate what happens? I don't believe both mainline compilers agree and wrong here.

Comment: rvalue objects that aren't fundamentals like int, float or pointers, aren't necessarily const. And in your example it isn't const.

Comment: @Konstantin Vladimirov  X{} is a non-constant object. So the non-constant method is selected.

Comment: `using const_X = X const; foo(const_X{});` does the other one.

Comment: @Konstantin Vladimirov By the way do you visit rsdn?

Comment: Intuition behind non-const method is clear to me as well, thanks. But as I am reading standard, seems it works only if we have two identical ICS one passing through const one not.

Comment: Please leave only Baz (comment out Bar operator) and you will see everything works. Both ICS are viable and allowed.

Comment: They are both allowed, but `Bar` is favoured (in your example).  Something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167190/how-to-do-non-const-member-function-used-on-objects-left-side-and-const-member/76167264

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov A constant method may be called for a non-constant object. But a non-constant method may not be called for a constant object.

Comment: You can try `operator Baz() && { std::cout << "Bada boom\n"; return {}; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overload resolution C++ for const member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469135/overload-resolution-c-for-const-member-functions)

Comment: Better dup candidate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555950/distinguishing-between-user-defined-conversion-sequences-by-the-initial-standard

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I think it is obvious this is different case. There is no overload resolution between const and non-const foo in my question I have only one function foo with const argument.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer thanks it is really close and answer here is also great!

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov nevertheless the same rules apply to your question. You even confirmed it yourself by accepting the given answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo(X{})` attempts to initialize a parameter of type `const Foo&` with a prvalue of type `X`.

This falls under [[dcl.init.ref]/5.3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3.2), which directs us to [[over.match.ref]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref) to select a conversion function through overload resolution.

Both `operator Bar()` and `operator Baz() const` are candidates, but the former is a better match because its object parameter is not `const` ([[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6)).

So, the (only) conversion sequence from `X` to `const Foo&` goes through `Bar`. And we never rank it against another conversion sequence because there is only one `foo` anyway.

---

An ambiguity would arise in a situation like this:

```cpp
void foo(Bar);
void foo(Baz);
foo(X());
```

Now the call is ambiguous because the ICS from `X` to `Bar` is indistinguishable from `X` -> `Baz`, despite its first standard conversion sequence being better.